# Why is my picture not displaying after upload with Django-Userena?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-userena

When I go to edit a user profile and upload a new profile pic it does not show up.  Instead I see a broken link with the following error.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/site_media/media/mugshots/4cfb402cad.jpg

Using the URLconf defined in dealr.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$
^admin/
^accounts/

The current URL, site_media/media/mugshots/4cfb402cad.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

What is strange about this is that inside my project folder I actually have /site_media/media/mugshots/ and the exact file that was uploaded (with the same filename), so I'm not sure why it is not displaying the picture.  Do I need to do something to my URLS.PY to allow for the viewing of this file?  That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Have you configure your server to serve static files?
For debug servers it's https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 0):

It seems your server cannot find your files. Make sure you have configured your [static and media roots](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) in your settings.py (for manage.py runserver).

If you are using a production server you will need to tell it where those directories are.
As an example if you are working with nginx:

```
server {

    [...]

    location /static/ {
        alias  /path/to/my/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```